# How do I get 'hidden' property for a div with crispy forms?

Tags: jquery, css, django, django-crispy-forms

I would like my html to render with **'hidden'** as a property of the div:

```
<div class="some-class" hidden>
    <input id="field1"....... form stuff>
</div>
```

If my form looks like this:

```
class SomeForm(forms.ModelForm):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(SomeForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.helper = FormHelper()
        self.helper.layout = Layout(
            Div(Field('field1'), css_class="some-class"),
        )
```

**How would I go about doing this?** I can't seem to find this in the Crispy documentation. Right now I am doing it with jquery (after the page loads), and I could also add a class and then hide it in css, but how do I add the 'hidden' attribute to the div?

Comment: `hidden` is not a permitted attribute for divs in HTML. What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: If I inspect/edit the page and add hidden as an attribute to a div it hides it. Is doing this functional, but not recommended? Because it seems to work... Basically, I just want the div to `display:none`when the form is initially rendered, then will change to `display:block` through some conditional logic in jquery. I was just wondering if there was a way to do this through crispy forms.

Comment: Much much better to do this with a css class.

Comment: [`hidden` *is* a permitted value for divs in HTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/hidden)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [the docs](http://django-crispy-forms.readthedocs.io/en/latest/layouts.html#universal-layout-objects), you have a few options. You can hide a `field` with `type="hidden"`:

```
Field('field_name', type="hidden")
```

If you must hide the `div` as you show in your example, I would suggest just using a CSS class:

```
.some-class { display: none; }
```

However, the docs says crispy-forms supports all HTML5 attributes (like `hidden`) by just replacing dashes with underscores. It seems to follow that simply using `hidden="true"` should work then in your case:

```
Div(Field('field1'), css_class="some-class", hidden="true")
```